# cakephp global variable for controllers

Tags: php, cakephp, global-variables

I'm trying to change my database connection depending on who is trying to log in to my page.

What I need is a way to save the correct db name so its accessible by all my controllers.

Using a session would work, but I doubt its safe and/or good practice.
If I could set a variable in the AppController from my AccountsController that would be perfect. but basically any way that enables me to share a variable between all controllers.

In my AccountsController I query a standard database for the correct name. then I use `configure::write('CompanyDB', $myDbVar)`. this work fine for this controller, but I cant use `configure::read('CompanyDB')` in any other controllers.

In my AppModel i have a construct fucntion that sets the db connection depending on the value inside `configure::read('campanyDB')` as mentioned before, I need to use `configure::write('CompanyDB',$myDbVar)` in all my controllers for this to work.

In my Account Model I set the `$specific=true`. this tells the AppModel that it should use the construct and change the db connection.

```
class AccountsController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','Js');
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');
    var $uses = array('User', 'Company');
    public $name = 'Accounts';
    public $myDbVar='coolbeans';

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        Configure::write( 'companyDB',$this->myDbVar);
    }   
}

class AppModel extends Model {
    var $specific = false;
    function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        if ($this->specific) {
            // Get saved company/database name
            $dbName = Configure::read('companyDB');
            // Get common company-specific config (default settings in database.php)
            $config = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('companySpecific')->config;
            // Set correct database name
            $config['database'] = $dbName;
            // Add new config to registry                 
            ConnectionManager::drop('companySpecific');
            ConnectionManager::create('companySpecific', $config);
            // Point model to new config
            $this->useDbConfig = 'companySpecific';
        }
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    }
}

class Account extends AppModel {

    public $primaryKey = '_id';
    //var $useDbConfig = 'mongo';
    var $specific = true;
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably best bet would be to go with a Configuration file:

**Reading and Writing Configuration Files:**
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#reading-and-writing-configuration-files

The basic idea is, you create a file in your `Config/` directory with settings for your app, then, in the bootstrap, you load that config file, which makes any of those variables available anywhere in the app.

Example file:  `Config/dbconnections.php`

```
<?php
$config = array(
    'MyAppDBs' => array(
        'company1' => 'connectionName',
        'company2' => 'differentConnectionName
    )
);
```

In your bootstrap file:

```
Configure::load('dbconnections');
```

Anywhere in your App:

```
$whatever = Configure::read('MyAppDBs.companyDB');
```

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong. but this would require me to pre populate the config files with all the companies? i was hoping to find a more dynamic solution.
but thanks :)

Comment: @user2596886 - If you're trying to keep track of database connections, I assume you don't want to connect to a database to retrieve which connection to use.  Therefore, a file seems the next obvious choice.  Simply write a function to update the config file whenever you add a new company and voila - "dynamic". :)  If, on the other hand you DO want to connect to a database to determine which OTHER database connection to use, simply do exactly what you're doing, but do it in the AppController's beforeFilter instead of a specific controller.

Comment: ahh, i guess i could make a function to update that file. will look into that.
About the Appcontroller, i dont know how i would pass the value retrieved in the controller into my appcontroller.

Comment: @user2596886 - is there a reason it needs to be set in the specific controller?

Comment: I dont know the name of the company befor i query the db.
I have a default db which contains a list of all companies and their users. when a user tries to log in i first query the default database to figure out which company he belongs to. when i know that, i can switch the db and log the user in properly + load all the content.

Comment: When you add a new company into the database, ALSO add it to your config file.  Your config variables are available at ANY point throughout the App, so - if you need to find the connection for the current company, just `Configure::read('MyAppDBs::'.$companySlug);`

Comment: what i wrote befor was to answer why i couldnt just set it in the appcontroller. i can see how a config file would work.
I'm off for today. i'll give your approach a go tomorrow. thanks dave

Answer (score 0):

I think if you do this

```
configure::write('CompanyDB', $myDbVar);
```

in your appController then you can access it in any controller using

```
configure::write('CompanyDB',$myDbVar);
```

since all controller inherits appController.